# jodd.bean.BeanException: Simple property not found: cId Invalid property: 'TradingCategoryImpl#cId'

Tags: liferay-6, alloy-ui

I meet the following problem
I am using AlloyUI to implement a portlet in Liferay

with the following code

```
 <liferay-ui:search-container-row
    className="com.handysoft.tp.model.TradingCategory"
    keyProperty="cId"
    modelVar="category">

  <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
      name="category-name"
      value="<%= category.getCName() %>" />
  <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp
      path="/admin/action.jsp"
      align="right" />

</liferay-ui:search-container-row>
```

Portlet still works but I meet the following error

```
jodd.bean.BeanException: Simple property not found: cId Invalid property: 'TradingCategoryImpl#cId'
```

If I change one small section to

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
      name="category-name"
      property="cName" />
```

The error happen in with both cName and cId. Nothing is appear, could u help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

FeinesFabi is right. It seems that Liferay Search container doesn't take the property names which has more than 1 capital letters in it.

For ex. if a property is tClassId then it won't work but tclassId will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.

Renaming the primary key from `gID` to `glossarId` an re-running the service builder fixed it for me. I don't understand why, though.